# This is not permitted when the subquery follows = != < <= > >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-delete

```
delete from gust_card

where gust_card.c_id =
(select gust_card.c_id``
from gust_card,booking,room
where
 gust_card.c_id=booking.c_id and
booking.room_id=room.room_id
and room.stranded='deluxe ' )
```

i want to delete  the records of customers who have booked ‘**Deluxe**’ rooms.

```
room table>> room_id , standard

guest_card table>> guest_id, guest name

booking table >> booking_id ,room_id,guest_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the equal sign with "IN" like

```
WHERE gust_card.c_id
IN (SELECT  gust_card.c_id
```

because the subselect can return more than one result row. With "in" all your rows with an id in the result list of the subselect can deleted.